# Scroll to item in listview in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, listbox, scroll

I have a silverlight 3 app with a textbox on the main window and a childwindow that has a list of all the potential textbox values.  When I open that childwindow I want it to scroll to the correct one in the list.

I'm trying to do this with the code below...using the ScrollIntoView.  It was not working at all until I add the UpdateLayerout().  However it does not seem to work all the time.  At times it scrolls but not all the way to the item, it is a few items higher than it should be.  The listbox is in an Accordion and the list items use a ItemTemplate\DataTemplate, not sure if that effects anything but thought I'd mention it.

Any ideas what I'm missing in the code below?

What I would like is to scroll the item to the top of the list ....any ideas how to that?

(Or any other suggestions on how to code this better)

Thanks!

```
for (int index = 0; index < myList.Items.Count; index++) {
        object obj = myList.Items[index];
        var listItem= obj as listItemObject;
        if (listItemObj != null)    {
            if (string.Compare(listItemObj.id, _PastedInId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0) {
                selectThisIndex = index;
                scrollToThisItem = obj;
            }
        }
    }
    myList.SelectedIndex = selectThisIndex;
    if (scrollToThisItem != null){
        myList.UpdateLayout();
        myList.ScrollIntoView(scrollToThisItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the ItemsControlExtensions implementation from the Silverlight Toolkit, available at http://silverlight.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show?projectName=Silverlight&changeSetId=47051#637494

This has a `ScrollIntoView(FrameworkElement element)` method that may help.